# two number having same value in a mongo schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongodb for a discordbot and i have a schema for guilds where my bot is. but When i use it the log and the id properties are the same

my code:

```
const testId = 745708447349342200;    
var testGuild = new Mongoose.Guild({
      authorized: [756541009621680249],
      name: "test Bot",
      id: tesstId,
      defautlMessage: "{user} à quitté le server",
      log: 745708447349342213,
    });
    console.log(testGuild.log); //display 745708447349342200
    Mongoose.Save(testGuild);
```

my Schema

```
const GuildSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String },
  id: { type: Number, unique: true },
  authorized: [{ type: Schema.Types.Number }],
  defaultMessage: { type: String },
  log: { type: Number, unique: true },
});
```

i've tried removing the *unique: true* in the schema but it doesn't change anything.
Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the type to string because Js rounds up a big number. This is not a problem od Mongo but js.

Try type in the browser console

```
x = 745708447349342213
```

and

```
x
```

You will see

```
745708447349342200
```

To fix your problem simple change `Number` to `String` in your model and operate on strings like:

```
x = `745708447349342213`
```

---

In JS

```
745708447349342213 === 745708447349342200
```

gives `true`. The max value of int where this problem does not exist is: `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` and equal to `9007199254740991`.

Comment: You are welcome in the awesome stack overflow community Yoyo. You can mark the answer as accepted if it helped to solve your problem.